# Bootstrap 3 tooltips refuse to work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page which is loaded using jquery:

```
$('#friends2').load("/pages/share/includes/current.php");
```

On that page I'm trying to use tooltips:

```
<img src="/img/path.jpg" class="Tool" title="hello world" data-toggle="tooltip">
```

But nothing happens, no tooltip, I've also tried adding the script files in again, just bootstrap.js and also bootstrap and jquery but none of them make the tooltips work - is there a better solution?

I've added:

```
$(function () { 
    $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); 
});
```

No change... also tried:

```
$(function () { 
    $(".Tool").tooltip(); 
});
```

No change... also tried no title and adding:

```
data-original-title="hello world"
```

**UPDATE**

I will stress that I have tooltips working on the same page just not within the DIV with ID `friends2` where I am loading this data

On the main page I have:

```
$('#editAccount,#listsTour').tooltip();
```

But adding `.Tool` to this does not work either

**UPDATE2 - THE ANSWER**

After looking hard and long I've found that one of the parent divs was set with overflow:hidden which of course blocks anything outside of it, like a tooltip! This is what dev vs production learns to smile at! I guess! Still trying...

Many thanks for answers, they are appreciated.

Comment: It appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/NxVTU/4/

Comment: Have updated question

Comment: Does @petkopalko's answer work for you?

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab/console?

Comment: Don't know what that is?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you calling tooltip funcion on AJAX generated content. Function is called before the content exists. Try to call `$(".Tool").tooltip();` in callback of load function.

```
$('#friends2').load("/pages/share/includes/current.php", function(){
    $(".Tool").tooltip(); 
});
```

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but I am 99% sure that problem is AJAX content, because tooltip works everywhere else except of #friends2.